# Quickly finding custom class in xib file

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in a kind of situation to check if any of components (say UILabel) in my nib file specified custom class in identity inspector.

Currently the only way to find out is to go and check each component in every xib, is there any way we can search for it, similar to way where we can search for the occurrence of particular class in the Xcode, and the Xcode will quickly tell us which xib file contains the UILabel of that specific custom classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I would suggest to use command `grep` in terminal(Xcode could not search .xib file):

```
grep -i -r --include=*.xib "TextToFindHere" /PathToSearchHere
```

Another way is to right click your .xib file and `Open As` `Source Code` and use `Command+F` to search. But this method can only search one file a time.